# Putting data in dataset into datatable?

Tags: c#

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
string filePath = @"C:\DRMF.xls";        

FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);

excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;

DataSet results = new DataSet();
DataTable testSheet = new DataTable();
testSheet = results.Tables.Add("test");          

results = excelReader.AsDataSet();
```

I had assumed that once I added the datatable "test" to the dataset, that any data that I loaded into the dataset would automatically load into the datatable "test".  That doesn't appear to be the case.  It is loading, instead, into a datatable called "Sheet1" which I assume it is getting from the Excel spreadsheet.

So, my question is, once I have the data in my dataset, how can I get it into the "test" datatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DataSet results = new DataSet();
results = excelReader.AsDataSet();
results.Tables["Sheet1"].TableName = "test";
```

This way, you have the data loaded and then you can change the table name to whatever you want and not have to create extra tables.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!